Checking if primary key value of a table is being referenced across other schemas
I have 1 database with 3 schemas,
one of the table from the schemas is primary_table (sample)
the primary table has a column primary_id (sample)
In postgres sql, how do you check if the value of the primary_id (example pid_1) from the table primary_table  is being referenced across other schemas
SELECT
    tc.constraint_name,
    tc.table_schema AS referencing_schema,
    tc.table_name AS referencing_table,
    kcu.column_name AS referencing_column,
    ccu.table_schema AS referenced_schema,
    ccu.table_name AS referenced_table,
    ccu.column_name AS referenced_column
FROM
    information_schema.table_constraints AS tc
    JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
        ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
    JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
        ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
WHERE
    tc.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
    AND ccu.table_name = 'primary_table'
    AND ccu.column_name = 'primary_id'
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM primary_table
        WHERE primary_id = 'pid_1'
        limit 1);


Using psql do \d sample. If you want to know how psql does it start psql with -E, that will show you the queries it uses to get the information in the output of \d sample. It will be the query that starts SELECT conname, conrelid::pg_catalog.regclass AS ontable, ...
